# how to generate xml file using libxml2 in c++?

Tags: c++, libxml2

I want to have following xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE people SYSTEM "XMLSpyDTD.dtd">
<report>
    <Start>
        <date format="ddMMyy" val="Tue Jun 09 2015&#x0A;" />
        <time format="hhmm" val="11:43:06 " />
    </Start>
    <test name="Testadd" executed="Yes">
        <discription>
            <![CDATA[Add two numbers]]>
        </discription>
        <targets>
            <target threaded="false">C++</target>
        </targets>
    </test>
</report>
```

So, kindly suggest me how may i generate it using libxml2 in c++?

Comment: Do you mean to read this XML file into a tree data structure using libxml2? If so, check out the [examples](http://www.xmlsoft.org/examples/#Parsing) and [documentation](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-lib.html).

Comment: @jens i want to parse this complete xml file using libxml2 in c++, in more simple words i only want to create this xml by using libxml2 in c++

Comment: It already *is* [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML): XML is a text file format to express structured data.